# Use MSAL to access ObjectID in azure python sdk?

Tags: python, azure, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to create a new Azure Key Vault using python. It requires the service principal `ObjectID`.

```
vault = kv_client.vaults.create_or_update(
    `myRgGroupName`,
    `myKeyVaultName`,
    {
        'location': 'westus',
        'properties': {
            'sku': {
                'name': 'standard'
            },
            'tenant_id': os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID'],
            'access_policies': [{
                'tenant_id': os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID'],
                'object_id': OBJECT_ID,
                'permissions': {
                    'keys': ['all'],
                    'secrets': ['all']
                }
            }]
        }
    }
)
```

**How can I access ObjectID programmatically using either Azure CLI or python sdk?**

**Can the MSAL library be used? If so, how?**

None of the [examples](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python) have this scenario outlined.

I do not want to go to the portal and get this information from Active Directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, the easiest way in your case is to use Azure CLI in python.

And you should know the `ObjectID` could be the object id of the user or service principal or security group in Azure AD, it depends on your requirement. if you are not familiar with access policy of keyvault, you can see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#data-plane-and-access-policies).

So to get the `ObjectID`, use the command below.

- Use [`az ad user list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-user-list) to get the `objectId` of the user.

[image]

- Use [`az ad group list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-group-list) to get the `objectId` of the security group.

[image]

- Use [`az ad sp list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-list) to get the `objectId` of the service principal.

[image]

Comment: Excellent reference. Thanks Joy